# In Angular, mat-sort-header is having a property of text-align: center. I want to override it and text-align:right. But it is not working

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am not able to override text-align: center in mat-sort-header

I have created a new class and added text-align: right in that class but it is not working.

It is taking the text-align: center from mat-sort-header and not allowing to text-align: right.

Comment: Have you tried adding `!important` to the style? Most of the angular material styles are created as encapsulated styles or inline styles, which makes probably higher priority than your custom css class.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `!important` for your class.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to align the contents of the header to the right. It won't work by changing the `text-align` property. If you inspect the element in the DOM, you'll see that the `mat-sort-header` directive puts an additional flex container inside the header, which contains both the header text and the sort arrow. To alight the content to the right, you have to apply `justify-content: end;` on that container.

You can add additional class on the header:

```
<th class="centered-header" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </th>
```

And define the class in the global `styles.scss`:

```
.centered-header {  
  .mat-sort-header-container {
    justify-content: end;
  }
}
```

Or you can just set it globally without adding new class:

```
.mat-sort-header-container {
    justify-content: end;
}
```

Note that since this happens inside a new component injected through a directive, this needs to happen in global styles. Alternatively you can use `::ng-deep` and place it in your component style, but it will still be promoted to global style (read [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#component-styling-best-practices)), so the effect is pretty much the same.

Here's an [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/khf9sa) based on the example from the official docs.